# WebRequest to IIS fails with timeout when run from console application

Tags: c#, iis, timeout, webrequest

I have most basic possible code which tries to get response from WebRequest. It sets timeout to 500ms (which is more than enough), and gets the response. It returns the information if the request was timed out or not. When I run this code from my computer connected via VPN to the server running IIS - everything works fine. This code returns "OK.". The same code run at IIS server returns "Timed out.". Always.

Please notice, I've double-checked the URI is valid, both by running this code at my computer, and testing this URI in InternetExplorer on IIS server machine.

The file Pulse.aspx is a simple text file containing 1 character "1". It IS accessible via URI I provided in the code.

Machine running IIS is Windows 2008 Server with all recent updates installed.

What's interesting - the message "Timed out." is displayed after over 2000ms, not 500ms, so it's not a normal timeout. On my computer I can set timeout value to 100ms, and then it times out, but it happens immediately (after real 100ms).

I tried to run my test code as a regular user and as Administrator user. No joy.

What am I doing wrong? I really NEED to run this code from IIS server (it's a part of a watchdog/pulse service which detects IIS crashes).

Here's the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {

        private static bool CheckForTimeout(Uri uri, int timeout) {
            var status = false;
            var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Timeout = timeout;
            WebResponse res = null;
            try {
                res = req.GetResponse();
            } catch (WebException x) {
                status = x.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout;
            } finally {
                if (res != null) res.Close();
            }
            return status;
        }        

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (CheckForTimeout(new Uri("http://192.168.1.11/Pulse.aspx"), 500))
                Console.WriteLine("Timed out.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("OK.");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I made it to work after changing timeout to 5000! But it's still very weird. Why do I need only 300ms running the code from remote host, and 5000ms running the same code from localhost?

Comment: what do you mean by "The same code run at IIS server returns "Timed out."." ? Are you running a console application on IIS?

Comment: No. I run a console application on a server which runs IIS. Both application and IIS are on the same server.